# Запуск функции и класса одновременно python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите пожалуйста как запустить функцию и класс одновременно, пробовал вот так:

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from multiprocessing import Process


def test2():
    while 1:
        print('Hello world')



class Test1(App):
    def click(self, args):
        if self.button.text == "Вкл":
            self.button.background_color = [1,0,0,1]
            self.button.text = "Выкл"
        elif self.button.text == "Выкл":
            self.button.text = "Вкл"
            self.button.background_color = [.15, .70, .24, 1]


    def build(self):
        self.button = Button (
            text = "Вкл",
            font_size = 20, 
            background_color = [.15, .70, .24, 1],
            pos_hint= {'x': .65,'top': .15},        
            size_hint = (.21,.11), 
            background_normal = '',
            on_press = self.click
        )
        return self.button

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = Process(target=Test1)
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=Test2())
    p2.start()
```

Comment: У родительского класса `App` определён метод `__call__`? Не пользовался `kivy`.

Comment: Там в классе App не объявлен, но у него родительский EventDispatcher, который находится в файле .pxd, а на нем мои способности "все"

Comment: Короче. Что Вы понимаете под *запустить класс*? Что надо вызвать?

Comment: Каждому приложению `Kivy` требуется создать подкласс `App` и переопределить метод `build()`.  Потом запустить через функцию `run()`. Дак вот если я буду запускать через нее, будет ошибка  `TypeError: run() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

Comment: Понял. Сейчас напишу ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что в Вашем варианте неправильно:

- `p1 = Process(target=Test1)` - тут Вы в качестве `target` передаёте класс (даже не экземпляр!!). Т.е. предполагается, что в процессе будет запущено `Test1()` (или, то же самое, `Test1.__call__()`) - звучит странно, согласитесь.
- `p2 = Process(target=Test2())` - тут Вы в качестве `target` передаёте **результат** выполнения функции `Test2`. Но в функции `Test2` бесконечный цикл, так что результат оттуда не вернётся. Но если даже функция что-то вернёт, это значение должно быть вызываемым (например, другая функция).

---

Как правильно:

- `p1 = Process(target=Test1().run)` - создаётся **экземпляр** (`()`) класса `Test1`, затем в процессе будет вызван метод `run` **экземпляра** (ошибка `self` из Вашего комментария).
- `p2 = Process(target=Test2)` - в отдельном процессе будет "крутиться" функция `Test2` (а не результат из неё, как в Вашем варианте).

Comment: Ошибку понял. Теперь `File line 82, in steal_handle
    _winapi.PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, False, source_pid)
OSError: [WinError 87] Параметр задан неверно`

Comment: Лучше задайте новый вопрос с хорошим описанием проблемы и полным текстом ошибки.